# How to aggregate text in c?

Tags: c, linux

how can i aggregate text from different sources for example

```
char * a , * b,* c, *d;
a = argv[1] ;
b = "something";
c = "another text";
d=b&a&c; //this what i want to know
printf("%s",d);
```

output :

somethingTESTanother text

Comment: Switch to c++ and declare d as std::string.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get some memory for saving the resulting string.
You can allocate just enough memory using `malloc()`; or (easier but does not scale) define `d` as an array with *enough* space (eg `char d[8000];`).

Then, after you have space for the result, you can `strcpy()` and `strcat()`; or `sprintf()` (if using C99 prefer `snprintf()`); or a number of other ways.

```
char *a, *b, *c, *d;
a = argv[1];
b = "something";
c = "another text";
int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s%s", a, b, c);
d = malloc(n + 1);
if (!d) /* error */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
snprintf(d, n + 1, "%s%s%s", a, b, c); //this what i want to know
printf("%s\n",d);
free(d);
```